# "expression cannot be used as a function" in return statement

Tags: c++, expression, emplace

Code (also
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8deX0.png)):

```
/***
Attempts to emplace new_vert in vertices,
    returning false
        if it failed (i.e., the vertex was already in vertices)
    or true
        if it succeeded
***/
template <typename T>
bool Graph<T>::addVert(const T& new_vert) {
    return vertices.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(new_vert),
        std::forward_as_tuple()).second();
};
```

As the screenshot shows, the error occurs on the last parenthesis of "`.second()`".

`vertices` is of type `std::map<T, std::set<T>>`, and `emplace()` [should return a `pair<iterator,bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/), with the bool accessible via `second()`, hence returning it. Different versions of the code (e.g., catching the pair with a variable `foo` and returning `foo.second()`) makes no difference; the error follows the last parenthesis of `second()`.

Looking at other questions with this error, they seem to boil down to operators missing somewhere, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Why is it happening?

Comment: `first` and `second` are not functions, but member variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `second` member of `std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) is a member variable, not a member function. You just need to omit the parentheses, as you're getting its value (as opposed to calling it):

```
return vertices.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(new_vert),
    std::forward_as_tuple()).second;
```